# What does "usage of /" mean on this screen?

Tags: server, disk-usage

[image: ubuntu server login screen]

I am purchasing a Ubuntu Server machine specified with a 480GB SSD. I am interpreting the said line as the root directory has a 195-ish GB in memory. I am confused!

[image: added df command screenshot]

Comment: Type `df` and get back to us.

Comment: I would take it to mean that root is using 3% of the partition, which would be close to 6GBs of the 195GB partition.

Comment: I added the `df` command screenshot. I sum'd all the bytes to be ~ 200gb.

Comment: @MartinThornton Thanks. I'll take a look at that later, as I am away from the server. And the server hasn't been set up for ssh.

Comment: @darth_epoxy `df` might be not the right thing here as it only shows mounted partitions. `lsblk` is more appropriate.

Comment: `fdisk -l` will be more helpful here...

Comment: Different folders are in different disk partitions. In your case, `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` is the root filesystem.

Comment: Note that you are using LVM - logical volumes. Its multiple volumes in one large partition. Often ESP & /boot are only two partitions outside the large LVM. You cannot use standard partitioning tools on LVM. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm & https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/advanced-installation.html

Comment: finally get my hands on my system. thanks all, thanks @oldfred. Yes, it's LVM. https://askubuntu.com/questions/202613/how-do-i-check-whether-i-am-using-lvm