How to rescue personal data on M2 SSD post failed 220.04 to 24.04 update?
Having accepted the invitation to update to 24.04 from 22.04 I have a none usable PC. After some days I have managed to create a 'Ubuntu 24.04 live disc' and boot my pc to it, I think!
My aim is to get access to my home folder on the SSD which has 'LVM'. Using Files I am informed that /home/ has 561 items totalling 11 MB with 8.3 GB free, this is not what I expected for a 500 GB SSD. In GParted it lists /dev/nvme0n1 as 476.94 GiB; /dev/nvme0n1p1 as EFI System Partition fat32 512MiB flagged as boot,esp; /dev/nvme0n1p2 locked lvm2pv 476.44 GiB used flagged as lvm. $ sudo lvscan reports that '/dev/vgubuntu/root' and '/dev/vgubuntu/swap_1' are Active.
Doing 'sudo vgchange -a n vgubuntu' and then 'sudo vgchange -a y vgubuntu' has not changed visibility of my files. 'sudo vgscan' obtained volume group as vgubuntu.
How do I get the files in my /home/ visible and then copy them off on to a USB HDD?
I did not encrypt the M2 SSD when I originally installed Ubuntu, just chose LVM.
Here is a screen shot to provide the information referred to by David and user 68186,
Terminal output + Disks + Disc Usage Analyzer:

I was unable to  use the fancy brackets for terminal output as I am using a different pc to do this post, no internet on the busted one at present! Hope this all works and you can see the screen shot.
I have noted that pvdisplay is in dispute with Disks and Disc Usage Analyzer about how full the disc is!
Thank you everyone, your answers have all been used to help me first understand and then actually copy my files on to an external hard drive.
The key answer seems to have been removed!? That was that I could click on the underlined Red coloured file route/name in Discs and then I could see my files and have access to them! For me this has been educational. I am 'slow' to respond because it has taken me this long to actually understand enough of what you have been saying and be able to actually do it.
I had also wanted to 'accept an answer', but it seems to have been removed plus I have been unable to discover how I would do that!

Please see answer that I did not encrypt drive in change to my original question.

I am not an expert on LVM. However, could you append to you question the output of 'sudo pvscan' and if successful then 'sudo pvdisplay' Please use {} to format (at top of edit box).

Try the app called Disks while booted from the Live Ubuntu USB (use the Try Ubuntu option). It should let you mount the LVM.

Thanks for adding the details to your question. Why is DISKS seeing the partition as ext4? Is that right? How have you mounted it? Can you append the result of the following command: 'sudo cat /etc/fstab'. (Just the mount of relevant partition will do). It is my understanding it should look something like '/dev/mapper/vg_test-lv_test' or '/dev/dm-#' If you run 'sudo gparted' does it identify it as 'lvm2-pv' and have a 'lvm' flag?

Based on the screenshot of the disks, you should be able to navigate to /media/ubuntu/33239478-67c7-45fb-b1f8-36178c67c8f4/home/ and copy the contents of the folder with your username.

I am deleting my answer since you didn't find it useful.

I'm not expert on LVM either, but here is what I got from using Arch with LVM in LUKS2:
You need to mount the disks to access them. Gparted is unable to do that afaik.
First, unmount the disks since they seem to be mounted somewhere under /media in your screenshot:
# umount /dev/vgubuntu/root

Then mount them somehwere you can find them:
# mkdir /mnt/old-root
# mount /dev/vgubuntu/root /mnt/old-root

Then check if you can access the files in there.

See answer in link for picture of gparted showing a lvm partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/202613/how-do-i-check-whether-i-am-using-lvm

@david Yeah that's what I said, it shows the LVM superblock, but not the LVs inside it.
